# Parse a string into primitive values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I know there is parseInt, parseFloat, and other workarounds to parse Booleans and Arrays from a String in javascript.

What I would need is a method with similar behavior when you use a Object string to JSON parser and the result is a Object with type converted values.

Here is what I want:

```
parseToPrimitive("a string") => "a string"
parseToPrimitive("1") => 1
parseToPrimitive("true") => true
parseToPrimitive("[1, 2, 3]") => [1, 2, 3]
```

Any native solution for this or any library?

Comment: There's no native solution because it's an ambiguous problem. You'd need to determine exactly what sorts of things you'd be willing to parse. Something that would just "figure out" the string would be quite challenging (in general).

Comment: Parse it as JSON using `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Do you mean `parseToPrimitive("\"a string\"")` in your first example? It seems more logical to me.

Comment: In JavaScript objects are not primitive values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work

```
function parseToPrimitive(value) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(value);
    }
    catch(e){
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, though it seems the `value` is always a string and `toString` is unnecessary

Comment: oh, that worked.. I was thinking about testing it before creating the question, but now I found that it may be the best way to accomplish my goal :)

Comment: parseToPrimitive('{a: 1}') // "{a: 1}"

Comment: Does not work for hexadecimal or binary notations.
`parseToPrimitive("0x10"); // "0x10"`

Comment: or `NaN` or `undefined`, although `undefined` isn't technically a primitive.